# What function is called when a Nib is unloaded?

Tags: ios, swift

I understand that when a Nib file is loaded into a window/view, it will call `awakeFromNib()` method.

My question is what function will be called when a Nib is about to be unloaded?

Thanks.

A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nibs do not die. They are not "unloaded". There is no event to detect. That is not how nibs work. There is nothing to unload!

Nib loading is merely a form of object instantiation - the objects at the top level of the nib. Once those objects are instantiated, the nib loading has done its work. Think of a nib as a coded set of instructions for instantiating and configuring some objects: "make a new UIView, give it this size, give it this background color..." That's all a nib is. To load a nib is merely to read and follow these instructions.

When you say `let x = "hello"` a string comes into existence. You do not ask for an event to tell you when the string has *finished* coming into existence. It comes into existence, and you capture it or it vanishes in a puff of smoke. Exactly the same is true of a nib. Nib loading means that the nib makes instances and delivers them to you. You capture them or you don't. If you don't, they vanish. End of story.

Comment: Might help you to read my book on this topic: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_nib_loading_and_file_8217_s_owner

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "die". Nibs don't die, they're just files. However, Nib (XML) files get read into memory and from the XML a variable is instantiated. That variable will eventually be deallocated (unless you have a memory leak) in which case `deinit` will be called which is the closest thing to what you're describing.

Comment: A nib is not a "variable" and it is not "read into memory". It's just a delivery vehicle for instantiating the objects its describes.

Comment: @matt No where did I say a nib is a variable.

Comment: You said "nibs get read into memory and the variable you get from that...". Nibs do not "get read into memory" and you do not get "a variable from that". Nibs are an instruction booklet for instantiating some objects. Loading a nib is just like giving a bunch of object-instantiation and object-configuration commands. That's all it is.

Comment: @matt We're describing the same thing (at least in my mind). I've revised my answer to be more explicit.

Comment: @Kevin Actually... No. In Swfit it's `deinit`, not dealloc. In Objective-C it's `-dealloc`. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Deinitialization.html